# libtf.so cannot open shared object file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using a package done by myself on fuerte and I have moved this package on Turtlebot which is on electric. But it's not working on electric, I have a error message when I execute roslaunch mypackage mylaunchfile.launch:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
process[vision_odometrie-1]: started with pid [30562] [vision_odometrie-1] process has died [pid 30562, exit code 127]. log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/2827a526-d4ef-11e2-a445-047d7b6f6b57/vision_odometrie-1*.log
```

The rosmake works without error and I have libtf.so in my directory /geometry/tf/lib

If I write:
ldd bin/vision_odometrie

libtf.so => /opt/ros/electric/stacks/geometry/tf/lib/libtf.so (0x00007f356cd0f000)

I have added this line on my .bashrc but that doesn't solve the problem:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/electric/stacks/geometry/tf/lib.libtf.so"

( I cannot do all the update because the linux version is old: Lucid Lynx 10.04LTS )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65151/libtf.so-cannot-open-shared-object-file/) by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running `make clean` in the package that throws the error, and then `make` .

---

Originally posted by [jastr](https://answers.ros.org/users/5201/jastr/) with karma: 26 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2013-06-24**:
Thanks for your answer. I did that and it's now working well. On the other side I have modified other stupid mistakes so I'm not sure my question was relevant.